# Unable to understand why I'm getting a substr error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running laravel, and my page is giving me a substr error. Only problem is, I'm not running any string conversion commands or anything...

I've tried even removing all the code from the tpl file, and I get the error, but when I remove the render() function's loop and just set the $output (which is the info the blade template loops through) to `$output=[];` then I don't get the error. ( PS: it's livewire)

Strange thing though, If I remove the loop that builds the $output completely, I don't get the error. But If I just manually set the `$output = []` which yields the same result as removing the loop. I then get the substring error.

Honestly the pattern does not make sense nor does the error message log below... I'm completely lost and completely frustrated... Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting the substr message?

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="theme-light">
<!--
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\resources\views\user\filemanager\index.blade.php) in file C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str.php on line 222

#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions-&gt;handleError(2, 'substr() expect...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 222, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str.php(222): substr(Object(Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter), -6)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php(103): Illuminate\Support\Str::endsWith(Object(Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter), Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php(77): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager-&gt;parseConnectionName(Object(Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1653): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager-&gt;connection(Object(Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1619): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::resolveConnection(Object(Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(1212): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model-&gt;getConnection()
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(1124): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model-&gt;getDateFormat()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(189): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model-&gt;asDateTime('2021-11-14 22:5...')
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(151): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model-&gt;addDateAttributesToArray(Array)
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1485): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model-&gt;attributesToArray()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(319): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model-&gt;toArray()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1485): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model-&gt;relationsToArray()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\livewire\livewire\src\HydrationMiddleware\HydratePublicProperties.php(229): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model-&gt;toArray()
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\livewire\livewire\src\HydrationMiddleware\HydratePublicProperties.php(209): Livewire\HydrationMiddleware\HydratePublicProperties::filterData(Object(App\Http\Livewire\Filemanager), 'selectedUser')
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\livewire\livewire\src\HydrationMiddleware\HydratePublicProperties.php(102): Livewire\HydrationMiddleware\HydratePublicProperties::dehydrateModel(Object(App\Models\User), 'selectedUser', Object(Livewire\Response), Object(App\Http\Livewire\Filemanager))
#16 [internal function]: Livewire\HydrationMiddleware\HydratePublicProperties::Livewire\HydrationMiddleware\{closure}(Object(App\Models\User), 'selectedUser')
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\livewire\livewire\src\HydrationMiddleware\HydratePublicProperties.php(130): array_walk(Array, Object(Closure))
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\livewire\livewire\src\LifecycleManager.php(141): Livewire\HydrationMiddleware\HydratePublicProperties::dehydrate(Object(App\Http\Livewire\Filemanager), Object(Livewire\Response))
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\livewire\livewire\src\LivewireManager.php(106): Livewire\LifecycleManager-&gt;initialDehydrate()
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(261): Livewire\LivewireManager-&gt;mount('filemanager')
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\resources\views/user/filemanager/index.blade.php(10): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('mount', Array)
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php(107): require('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php(108): Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::Illuminate\Filesystem\{closure}()
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine.php(58): Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem-&gt;getRequire('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Array)
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\livewire\livewire\src\ComponentConcerns\RendersLivewireComponents.php(35): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine-&gt;evaluatePath('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Array)
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine.php(61): Livewire\CompilerEngineForIgnition-&gt;evaluatePath('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Array)
#27 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\facade\ignition\src\Views\Engines\CompilerEngine.php(37): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine-&gt;get('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Array)
#28 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\View.php(139): Facade\Ignition\Views\Engines\CompilerEngine-&gt;get('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Array)
#29 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\View.php(122): Illuminate\View\View-&gt;getContents()
#30 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\View.php(91): Illuminate\View\View-&gt;renderContents()
#31 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php(69): Illuminate\View\View-&gt;render()
#32 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php(35): Illuminate\Http\Response-&gt;setContent(Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#33 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(794): Illuminate\Http\Response-&gt;__construct(Object(Illuminate\View\View), 200, Array)
#34 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(763): Illuminate\Routing\Router::toResponse(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#35 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(695): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#36 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate.php(44): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#41 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#42 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#43 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#44 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession.php(58): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#46 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#47 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#48 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession-&gt;handleStatefulRequest(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Session\Store), Object(Closure))
#49 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#50 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#51 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#52 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#53 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#54 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#55 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(697): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then(Object(Closure))
#56 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(672): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#57 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(636): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;runRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#58 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(625): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#59 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(167): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#60 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#61 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\livewire\livewire\src\DisableBrowserCache.php(19): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#62 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Livewire\DisableBrowserCache-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#63 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\barryvdh\laravel-debugbar\src\Middleware\InjectDebugbar.php(60): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#64 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\InjectDebugbar-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#65 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#66 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#67 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#68 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#69 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#70 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#71 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#72 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#73 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#74 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#75 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\fruitcake\laravel-cors\src\HandleCors.php(38): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#76 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#77 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#78 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#79 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#80 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(142): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then(Object(Closure))
#81 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(111): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#82 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\public\index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#83 {main}
```

**Important Side Note**
The odd thing is. This loop connects via FTP to collect folders. If I change the FTP user credentials to another user's credentials, I don't get the error. So it's something in this user's directories (it would seem), but boh user's directories only have 1 folder, same folder name too. So everything matches from what I can see perfectly between the two.

I can also login with FileZilla to both. So it's not a server issue I think...

**Second Site Note**
I checked on the FTP server logs and noticed something different's happening.

If logged into the 1 user (that does not give the error), I am just seeing logged in confirmation then logout...
But with my user that's giving the issue I am noticing something different happening:

```
Nov 15 01:56:51 node1 pure-ftpd[7777]: (?@10.0.0.13) [INFO] test is now logged in
Nov 15 01:56:51 node1 pure-ftpd[7777]: (test@10.0.0.13) [INFO] Can't change directory to test.php: Not a directory
Nov 15 01:56:51 node1 pure-ftpd[7777]: (test@10.0.0.13) [INFO] Logout.
```

The part that's even odder is that the directory I am asking laravel to query is the / directory which only has the domains folder. The test.php is in the domains directory so it's not even being queried at the moment though?

**filemanager.index.blade**

```
<x-narrow-layout>    
    <x-slot name="content">
        @livewire('filemanager')
    </x-slot>
</x-narrow-layout>
```

**filemanager Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Http\Livewire\DataTable\WithPerPagePagination;
use App\Http\Livewire\DataTable\WithSorting;
use App\Http\Livewire\DataTable\WithCachedRows;

class Filemanager extends Component
{
    use WithSorting, WithCachedRows;
    
    public $showEditModal = false;
    public $showDeleteModal = false;
    public $selectedUserId = '';
    public $selectedUser = NULL;
    public $openDirectory = '';
    public $editing;
    public $editingFile;
    public $selected = [];
    public $selectPage = false;
    public $selectAll = false;
    
    public $filters = [
        'search' => ''
    ];
    
    protected $queryString = ['selectedUserId', 'openDirectory'];

    public function rules() {
        $rules = [
            'editing' => 'nullable'
        ];

        return $rules;
    }
    
    public function selectUserFtp($user_id){
        $this->selectedUserId = $user_id == $this->selectedUserId ? '' : $user_id;
        $this->openDirectory = '';
    }
    
    public function updateActivePath($path){
        $this->openDirectory = $path;
    }
    
    public function editFile($file){
        $this->editing = $this->selectedUser->MainFTPUser->GetFileContent($file);
        $this->editingFile = $file;   
        $this->showEditModal = true;
    }

    public function saveFile() {
        $this->validate();
        $this->selectedUser->MainFTPUser->SaveFileContent($this->editingFile, $this->editing);
        
        $this->showEditModal = false;
        
        $this->editing = '';
        $this->editingFile ='';
    }

    public function duplicateFile($file) {
        $this->editing = $this->selectedUser->MainFTPUser->GetFileContent($file);
        $this->editingFile = $file;
        
        $this->selectedUser->MainFTPUser->SaveFileContent($this->editingFile.'_copy', $this->editing);
        
        $this->editing = '';
        $this->editingFile ='';
    }

    public function deleteFile($file) {
        $this->selectedUser->MainFTPUser->deleteFile($file);
    }
    
    public function updatedSelectPage($value) {
        
            $this->selected = $value 
                    ? $this->Rows->pluck('id')->map(fn($id) => (string) $id)
                    : $this->selected = [];
    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        $sub_accounts_array = User::query()
                                ->where(function ($query) {
                                    $query->wherein('id', Auth::user()->SubUsersIDS)
                                    ->orWhere('id', Auth::user()->id);
                                })
                                ->orderBy('username')
                                ->get();
        
        $this->selectedUser = $this->selectedUserId!='' ? User::find($this->selectedUserId) : NULL;
                              
        $directoryContent = [];
        $directoryDirectories = [];
        $output = [];
        
        if($this->selectedUser!=NULL){
            $directoryDirectories = $this->selectedUser->MainFTPUser->DirectoryFolders($this->openDirectory);
            $directoryContent = $this->selectedUser->MainFTPUser->DirectoryFiles($this->openDirectory);
        }
        
        $output = [];
        foreach($directoryDirectories as $folder){
            $output[] = [
                'id' =>   md5($folder['path']),
                'path' =>   $folder['path'],
                'label' =>   $folder['label'],
                'size' =>   '1 kb',
                'permissions' =>   '0000',
                'date' =>   $this->selectedUser->MainFTPUser->getDateModified($folder['path']),
                'type' =>   'folder',
            ];
        }
        foreach($directoryContent as $file){
            $output[] = [
                'id' =>   md5($file['path']),
                'path' =>   $file['path'],
                'label' =>   $file['label'],
                'size' =>   $this->selectedUser->MainFTPUser->getFileSize($file['path']),
                'permissions' =>   '0000',
                'date' =>   $this->selectedUser->MainFTPUser->getDateModified($file['path']),
                'type' =>   'file',
            ];
        }

        return view('livewire.filemanager')
                ->with('sub_accounts', $sub_accounts_array)
                ->with('directoryFilesAndFolders', $output);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the file manager index page look like?

Comment: Can we see controller code and view code?

Comment: @mrhn I have added the controller code aswell as the views code for you to see

Comment: I tried pasting the view for livewire.filemanager but it says the body is too large. How can I share it with you guys @James

Comment: hmm... can you show us you config for the database you are using and what is the env for database name?

Answer (score 1):

From the error stack:

> #0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'substr() expect...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 222, Array)
>
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str.php(222): substr(Object(Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter), -6)
>
> #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php(103): Illuminate\Support\Str::endsWith(Object(Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter), Array)
>
> #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php(77): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->parseConnectionName(Object(Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter))
>
> #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1653): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->connection(Object(Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter))
>
> #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\mws\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1619): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::resolveConnection(Object(Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter))
>
> ...

The `Illuminate\Support\Str::endsWith` method is called on a `Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter` object instead of string.

`FilesystemAdapter` was first used in #5 of the stack (`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::resolveConnection`) then propagated through. There was a few Eloquent internal calls from that below. From lower level (#13 - #19), you can see a few livewire calls.

My guess is that your combined use of livewire with your Filemanager class might cause issue that results in using `FilesystemAdapter`, incorrectly, as the database connection string.

Comment: Hey bud, That's the thing. I've been reading through it and I saw the same. But I don't run an endsWith command at all. So I'm unsure of what the issue is.... And where it's sneaking in...

Comment: The `Str::endsWith` is called in your database connection, probably triggered by Model initialization. Don't know why a `FilesystemAdapter` is used there. You need to check your Model init code.

Comment: How would I check that? I don't define any on boot functions apart from observers. And i've disabled my observers to test....

Comment: Did you do anything with database or model at all?

Comment: I do work with the model. But the problem is, even if I remove all the model's functions to return null, I still get the same error. And none of them have anything to do with Str::endsWith at all?

Comment: Again, all model calls DatabaseManager::connection, and connection calls Str::endsWith. So you did call it indirectly.

Comment: I guess there could be an issue with your livewire usage.

Comment: I would agree. But the question is why does it work perfectly with one user's ftp details, But not with the other? My thought is something is different between the 2 causing it., But how to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok Guys, I was able to narrow it down.
Based on @koala's answer hinting that it was in the model, I had 2 functions:

```
$directoryDirectories = $this->selectedUser->MainFTPUser->DirectoryFolders($this->openDirectory);
$directoryContent = $this->selectedUser->MainFTPUser->DirectoryFiles($this->openDirectory);
```

Which if I commented them out, everything worked perfectly well.
Why I don't understand, because on any other user it was working perfectly...

but I moved all the "Functions" I had in the model, stuff like adding and removing FTP users, out of the model, leaving only the attributes and the relationships in there, and I moved the rest all to the livewire controller.

After doing this, It fixed my issue, I no longer had a substr issue.

I still don't understand why it was so unpredictable behavior, But thanks for the tips. That lead me to finding the issue.

Comment: Your old feature methods / properties in model probably overwritten some of the model (probably the User model) class or Livewire. That probably tricked Livewire into loading the FilesystemAdapter as connection string.

Comment: It would be benefiting for you to read about Single Responsibility Principle in [SOLID](https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/solid-principles-php). A class doing too many things can be a source of trouble that you don't want in a project. If you had separated features into different classes, you would probably have a less muddy situation to start with.

Comment: @KoalaYeung Agreed... I am going to seperate it out a bit and clean it up to avoid a future similar issue.